# WPF XBAP applications blank after second/third deploy?

Tags: wpf, xbap

This has happened repeatedly on various machines in VS2008 and Visual C# 2008.

I create an XBAP appliation.

I click the green arrow and it works.

I click Build/Publish and publish it to either a website or folder, it works.

I make some changes, publish again, and I just get a white screen. Both browsers, can restart, always blank.

It seems to be some kind of caching, etc. Has anyone had this happen to them and found a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the version number incrementing? Right click on the xbap project, go to properties/publish tab,  increase the version number and republish.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the application store using **mage -cc** command from VS command prompt. Check out [this](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/08-06-24/Tip_of_the_Day_Clear_your_ClickOnce_application_store.aspx) post for more info.